# ¿Cuál es el antónimo de "feminismo"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sustantivos

> NOTA: Este es un ejemplo de pregunta que, por un mal planteamiento, no salió como yo esperaba, y cuando quise rectificar ya era demasiado tarde. Así pues, yo mismo la he marcado como duplicada para que la gente que llegue aquí pueda acceder a la pregunta corregida. Dejo en todo caso esta pregunta abierta para su consulta y para no eliminar el trabajo de las personas que se tomaron la molestia de responderla.

---

En [este artículo de la Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/feminismo-no-es-lo-contrario-de-machismo/) se especifica que "machismo" y "feminismo" no son antónimos, puesto que se refieren a cosas distintas:

> [**machismo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NnO8B9D)
>
> 1. m. Actitud de prepotencia de los varones respecto de las mujeres.
> 2. m. Forma de sexismo caracterizada por la prevalencia del varón.
>
> **[feminismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HjuyHQ5)**
>
> 1. m. Principio de igualdad de derechos de la mujer y el hombre.
> 2. m. Movimiento que lucha por la realización efectiva en todos los órdenes del feminismo.

A mí me gusta explicar el feminismo como un vector de fuerza. Supongamos que el nivel de igualdad entre hombres y mujeres en la sociedad se pudiera medir situando un punto en un segmento `AB`. En el extremo `A` estaría la supremacía masculina total, y en `B` la supremacía femenina total. En el centro `O` está la igualdad entre sexos. La sociedad entiende que ahora mismo el punto se sitúa en el segmento `AO`, y el feminismo actúa como un vector de fuerza que hace que el punto se desplace hacia `O`.

El machismo no es el vector opuesto, sino que denota una actitud de prepotencia de hombres hacia mujeres que no tiene nada que ver con la teoría del segmento, sino que se puede dar en cualquier caso esté donde esté el punto situado en el segmento. A la actitud contraria al machismo se la denomina, según el artículo, *hembrismo*, y sería una actitud de prepotencia de la mujer hacia el hombre.

Volviendo a la teoría del segmento, si llegara el caso en el que el punto se desplazara tanto que llegara a situarse en el segmento `OB`, lo lógico sería que surgiera un movimiento, un vector de fuerza opuesto al feminismo, liderado por los hombres con la intención de devolver el punto nuevamente al centro. Este concepto sería el semánticamente opuesto al feminismo.

¿Cuál sería el término adecuado para este concepto opuesto al feminismo?

Comment: La cosa es que los idiomas no son tan lógicos como las matemáticas, la fuerza de la que hablas sería contraria a la del feminismo pero el concepto en si sería equivalente, buscaría la igualdad entre hombre y mujeres. Para mi `A` y `B` no son contrarios sino el mismo perro con distinto collar

Comment: This question seems to me a category mistake. Feminism is not the sort of thing which has an opposite any more than other philosophical movements have opposites.

Comment: @mdewey well, it could. See my comment to aparente's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Por supuesto uno de los "problemas" (con respecto a esta pregunta) con estos términos es que pese a estar fuertemente asociados con los sustantivos [macho](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NndQJAy%7CNnghkls) y [hembra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=K7vzjPm), pero significando respectivamente "prepotencia de los *machos* con respecto a las *hembras*" y "movimiento por la igualdad de *machos* y *hembras*".

Hay quien usa `hembrismo` para referirse a esa actitud que tu describes para el vector `OB`.

> Hembrismo es un discutido neologismo en español usado con distintas acepciones. Puede funcionar como sinónimo de misandria o desprecio a los hombres. Otras veces se define como **discriminación sexual hacia los varones, sesgos de género que perjudican a los varones en acciones u opiniones**, e incluso se usa para referirse al supuesto uso interesado del prestigio político ganado por el feminismo para promover un ideario represivo contra los hombres.
>
> fuente [wikipedia: hembrismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hembrismo)

Lo cierto es que también tenemos los términos:

> **[misántropo, pa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PNkt6Js)**
>
> Que siente o manifiesta misantropía (Aversión al género humano y al trato con otras personas)

Para las personas que no les gustan otras personas

> [**misógino, na**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PP5BGCW)
>
> Que siente o manifiesta misoginia (Aversión a las mujeres.)

Para las personas, hombres o mujeres, que no les gustan las mujeres.

> [**misándrico, ca**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PNhbTpI)
>
> Que siente o manifiesta misandria (Aversión a los varones.)

Para las personas, hombres o mujeres, que no les gustan las hombres.

Cabe destacar por cierto como están formadas estas palabras con las raíces griegas miseîn 'odiar', andrós 'varón', gynos, 'hembra' y anthrōpos 'humano' (más o menos).

Un feminismo bien entendido no sería misándrico. En la realidad, distintos individuos (auto)proclamados feministas tienen diversos intereses y sus ideologías estarán más o menos "radicalizadas" respecto a los posiciones (de poder) de los individuos de un sexo sobre el otro.

Quizá lo fácil, o lo lógico, habría sido tener los términos *machismo*, para los *misóginos*, *feminismo* para los *misándricos* e "igualismo" para los que no consideren que un sexo ostenta un "posición privilegiada" sobre el otro.

Y aquí un matiz, estoy usando mal los términos misógino/misándrico, puesto que estas personas sienten *aversión* hacia las personas de un cierto sexo y huyen del trato con ellas. Estos términos no implican necesariamente que alguien piense que un sexo está por encima del otro (Puede tratarse de [ginefobia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JCgFVY4) o [androfobia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2aUkryH)).

En cualquier caso, citando a [wikipedia sobre la misoginia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misoginia)

> La misoginia puede manifestarse de diversas maneras, que incluyen denigración, discriminación, violencia contra la mujer, y cosificación sexual de la mujer.
>
> De acuerdo con el sociólogo Allan G. Johnson, "la misoginia es la actitud cultural de odio hacia las mujeres, por el hecho de que son mujeres"

Sería fácil ver que "misógino" y "machista" son prácticamente sinónimos. Por tanto, podríamos proponer "misándrico" para ese "feminismo radical" (tu vector `OB`, o tu punto `B`) o quedarnos con el mencionado `hembrismo`.

Para responder claramente a tu pregunta, no hay opuesto de "feminismo", ya que es "el punto medio". El feminismo (bien entendido) es la lucha contra el machismo y el "hembrismo". El nombre para este término puede estar mal escogido (desde nuestra perspectiva actual), pero responde a motivos históricos y fue acuñado de la misma manera en que evoluciona el lenguaje.

Si llegásemos a una situación en la que viviésemos en el punto `B` y quisiéramos volver al `o`, el movimiento sería llamado "feminismo" porque es una búsqueda de la igualdad (Salvo que para ese entoces el significado y la definición de "feminismo" hubiese cambiado, dividiéndose en un "misandrismo"  y un "igualismo").

El antónimo de feminismo, o "lo opuesto" en un sentido amplio, ya que como sustantivo no tiene "técnicamente" un antónimo, sería "discriminación por razón de género".

---

EDIT: Podrías llamar a este movimiento "masculinismo" si quieres buscar algo "semánticamente opuesto" pero análogo al feminismo. Reitero, que el feminismo, tal y como se define ahora, representa al movimiento que busca la igualdad sin importar sus abanderados (mujeres u hombres) ni qué tipo de discriminación por género está combatiendo (prepotencia de hombres o de mujeres).

Si llegase ese punto en el que dijeses "el feminismo ya no es la lucha por la igualdad, si no solo la lucha por contrarrestar el machismo", podrías llamar "masculinismo" a ese movimiento que contrarrestaría el "hembrismo".

Comment: Por cierto, el antónimo de misoginia es, de acuerdo  a ese articulo de wikipedia, *filoginia*, el amor o agrado hacia las mujeres. Filántropo es por supuesto el de misántropo.

Comment: Te agradezco infinito tu reflexión, pero no estoy seguro de que esto responda a la pregunta. No sé si es que no he terminado de entender tu argumentación o si no he conseguido explicarme correctamente en la pregunta. El feminismo es un movimiento pacífico que para nada promulga el odio hacia los hombres, basado en contrarrestar la actual supremacía masculina y en la búsqueda de la igualdad. Si la situación fuera la inversa (hay supremacía femenina), ¿cómo se llamaría el movimiento igualmente pacífico que buscaría la igualdad contrarrestando dicha supremacía femenina?

Comment: `¿cómo se llamaría el movimiento igualmente pacífico que buscaría la igualdad contrarrestando dicha supremacía femenina?` **Feminismo.** Por definición. Como explico en la pregunta, hay una razón histórica para que sea "feminismo" y no "igualismo" (nació buscando justicia social y política para las mujeres, pero ahora busca la igualdad). El feminismo no busca "contrarrestar la supremacía masculina", si no la de un sexo sobre el otro. Tus vectores `AO` (antimisoginia) y `BO` (antimisandrismo) recibirían el mismo nombre de "feminismo", porque es un movimiento que busca la igualdad.

Comment: genial, ¡gracias por la aclaración! :-)

Comment: @Charlie, he hecho un edit con una cosa que se me ha ocurrido hoy en el metro. A ver si te gusta "masculinismo".

Comment: Lamento la confusión generada con esta pregunta. He abierto una nueva pregunta [aquí](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24450/12637), mucho más sencilla y que espero que refleje lo que realmente quería preguntar. He votado cerrar esta pregunta como duplicada de aquella. Si te animas, pásate y añade una respuesta allí.

Comment: No veo la necesidad para la otra pregunta. Esta respuesta responde esta y la otra. Siendo la otra posterior, es la que debe cerrarse como duplicada.

Comment: El concepto de [_masculinismo_](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masculinismo) tiene incluso su página en la wikipedia. Por otro lado, [la RAE reconoce que palabras como _feminazi_, _hembrismo_ y _masculinismo_ se usan](http://varonesunidos.com/masculinidad/la-rae-acepta-los-terminos-feminazi-hembrismo-y-masculinismo/) para expresar significados o sentidos (por ejemplo, despectivo) que no tenían término propio. Según parece, _masculinismo_ se usa habitualmente en estudios. Si su uso se generaliza y estas palabras aparecen en el registro escrito es muy probable que se incluyan en el diccionario.

Answer (score 1):

El feminismo se desarrolló como una nueva manera de analizar las relaciones entre hombres y mujeres, y de analizar la sociedad.  El feminismo nos señala la desigualdad de *poder*.  Clarence Thomas aprovechaba de su puesto como el jefe de Anita Hill para hostigarla; el sistema *sexista* de aquel entonces la dejaba aislada, sin manera de hacer frente a su hostigamiento (que era sistemático).  El feminismo presentó cifras estadísticas que comprobaron que las mujeres no recibían el mismo pago que los hombres que realizaban el mismo trabajo, es decir, que no había "equal pay for equal work".

Lo contrario del feminismo es el **sexismo.**

El sexismo es un sistema de creencias y un sistema legal.  Dentro del sexismo la mujer se limita por las respuestas represivas de individuos y de la sociedad.  Se limita hasta por sus propios temores.  Lo más feo de todo -- y esto yo no lo había visto antes de pasarme a vivir (desde EEUU) hasta México -- es cuando una mujer absorbe los valores sexistas hasta tal grado que ya ni cree en las posibilidades, y aplasta la esperanza de las niñas y las jóvenes más aún que los mismos hombres hacen.

Rechazo por completo tu análisis del segmento

[image: segmento AB]

El que rechaza el sexismo propone ideas feministas.

El que rechaza (o la que rechaza) el feminismo *es sexista*, es decir, se adhiere al *sexismo*.

Comment: Entiendo tu respuesta y la respeto. Déjame pues que te plantee la pregunta de otra forma. Imagina que el mundo se hubiera desarrollado de forma completamente opuesta en cuanto a sexos. Las mujeres tienen los puestos de responsabilidad y a los hombres se les discrimina y se les paga menos por ser hombres (por resumirlo rápido). El machismo pasa a ser hembrismo. ¿Cómo se llamaría en esa situación hipotética el movimiento equivalente a nuestro feminismo que buscaría la igualdad del hombre con respecto a la mujer?

Comment: @Charlie - Pues escribe un cuento de ciencia ficción o fantasía, inventa a un Gloria Steinem, desarrolla el tramo personal e histórico en tu cuento, y el término saldrá orgánicamente del cuento. Mira cómo los términos han evolucionado en los últimos cincuenta años.  Ahora tenemos, por ejemplo, *gender equality* (¿equivalente en español?).  ("Justicia" siempre está de moda....)

Comment: @charlie, comparto la respuesta de Aparente a tu pregunta y comentario. Esto es como si dijeses "Si el _racismo_ es la discriminación de los blancos a los negros, cómo se llamaría la discriminación de negros a los blancos?". Sería _racismo_ también. Como dice, en un universo de ciencia ficción podrías tener un machismo y hembrismo que hubiesen evolucionado de forma paralela (o un futuro alternativo donde perdiese su significado actual), y entonces no se acuñaría y usaría "feminismo" de la manera y con el significado actual. `Feminismo` describe lo que buscas, salvo escenarios de Ci-Fi.

Comment: @Diego - Gracias por tus argumentos de apoyo.  // Interesantemente, en EEU hay un término, "reverse racism", que viene siendo como el malinchismo en México.  Dime si quieres que explique el malinchismo.

Comment: Lamento la confusión generada con esta pregunta. He abierto una nueva pregunta [aquí](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24450/12637), mucho más sencilla y que espero que refleje lo que realmente quería preguntar. He votado cerrar esta pregunta como duplicada de aquella. Si te animas, pásate y añade una respuesta allí.