# ¿Cuál sería el opuesto etimológico de "feminismo"?

Tags: etimología, solicitud-de-término

Por plantear un sencillo ejercicio de etimología, cojamos la palabra *feminismo* y tratemos de buscar su opuesto etimológico. Según el diccionario, la palabra *[feminismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HjuyHQ5)* proviene del francés *féminisme* y este del latín *femĭna*. En español existe *[fémina](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HjmYDsU)*, pero no sé cuál es su opuesto masculino, luego además de la opción *masculinismo* que parece relativamente obvia, ¿existirían otras posibilidades?

¿Cuál se os ocurre que podría ser su opuesto etimológico?

---

> NOTA: Esta pregunta está hecha sin contexto a propósito, principalmente porque no lo hay. No es que quiera usar la palabra inventada para un libro ni nada. Es lo que es: un pequeño juego de etimología (por pura curiosidad y despojando a la palabra en sí de su significado) para ver qué se os ocurre.

Comment: Por lo que se refiere al latín, el opuesto es sin duda [_mascŭlus_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmasculus)

Comment: Ojo: Charlie se _curró_ esta pregunta para intentar expresar con más detalle lo que sintió que había quedado cojo en su anterior [¿Cuál es el antónimo de “feminismo”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24422/1674). Somos libres de votar como queramos, pero este voto negativo que ha recibido me hace daño: ¿podría explicarlo quien lo haya hecho? Viniendo la pregunta de alguien tan cuidadoso con las formas, creo que sería útil proporcionarle información al respecto para intentar ayudar a conseguir buenas respuestas.

Comment: @fedorqui agradezco tu comentario. La pregunta original también recibió un voto negativo, así que supuse que habría sido la misma persona, y no le di mayor importancia. Pero sí, me gustaría saber qué puedo hacer para mejorar esta pregunta.

Comment: la pregunta de charlie va en referencia a la etimologia y no al uso, 
el "feminismo" etimologico no tiene ninguna relacion con el uso que se le da, dado que el feminismo busca la igualdad, entonces su etimologia de femina pierde el sentido completametne

Comment: Yo es que al contrario que [fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/feminismo-no-es-lo-contrario-de-machismo/) sí que creo que *machismo* y *feminismo* son antónimos ya que el primero es una actitud  de superioridad de los hombres frente a las mujeres y el segundo propugna la igualdad. De hecho, como dije en la otra pregunta, si aceptamos el témino "hembrismo" sería en realidad el equivalente a *machismo* y no su contrario.

Comment: @blonfu tu punto de vista me parece muy interesante, y entiendo la idea que planteas. En todo caso, he tratado de desvincular en esta pregunta las palabras de su carga semántica, con la esperanza de facilitar así las posibles respuestas.

Comment: Ya tiene dos negativos :(

Comment: Respecto a los votos negativos, creo que a algunos les cuesta entender que esta pregunta tiene un sentido más "académico" o teórico que práctico. Ya discutimos sobre el significado de "feminismo" en la anterior pregunta, y queda claro lo que Carlos quiere preguntar (aunque estuviese buscando un término inventado para escribir su  relato de ciencia ficción). La pregunta no carece de valor interés por ello. La gente es libre de votar como quiera, pero ayudaría más decir por qué uno piensa que esta pregunta merece un negativo.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because in my opinion, the same as at ELU, our site should require a context and sample sentence showing how the word will be used.  Without that, when we try to read your mind to supply a word for you to use, we are shooting in the dark. (I only got around to reading and voting just now -- 1 am Wed. evening. I don't know about the previous downvotes.) Charlie tu aportas una gran cantidad de preguntas, bravo; nadie puede atinar el 100% de las veces.

Comment: @aparente001 el contexto lo intenté dar en la pregunta anterior (a la que respondiste) y me salió mal la jugada porque no se entendió lo que yo quería preguntar. Es más, te intenté explicar el contexto y me respondiste que me buscara yo mi propia respuesta. Intento liberar la pregunta de su contexto (consiguiendo así buenas respuestas que para nada han ido a ciegas), y la quieres cerrar por falta de contexto. No sé qué hacer para atinar con esta pregunta, pero en fin, cada cual es libre de votar lo que le plazca.

Comment: @Charlie - Es que el "feminismo" fue una palabra inventada, para significar algo mas o menos claro.  Bueno, no se a ciencia cierta porque no he leido lo suficiente de esa epoca historica.  Pero creo que las primeras feministas tenian sus ideas mas o menos definidas.  // Si quieres que inventemos o que propongamos un termino, debes definir mas o menos bien lo que quieres que represente tambien.  //  Por favor trae el contexto de la otra pregunta para aca para que esta este completa, si no, gente distraida como yo no va a seguir muy bien el hilo, perdon.

Comment: Creo que hay un movimiento en EEUU de *men's rights*, tengo la impresion muy borrosa de que por lo menos algunos de los proponentes traen much amargura porque algun juez les ha quitado los derechos de padre para con sus hijos.  Seguramente hay ideologia que les une tambien.  Sera eso lo que buscas, acaso?

Comment: @aparente001 no he puesto ningún contexto porque en realidad no lo hay. De la pregunta anterior se desprendió que estaba escribiendo un libro de ciencia ficción ambientado en un universo paralelo, pero no hay tal libro (más quisiera yo). Esta pregunta está hecha sin contexto a propósito, porque no quiero usar la palabra en ninguno en particular. Es simplemente un juego, un pequeño ejercicio etimológico, y como digo las respuestas que hay me están gustando. Si eso no te parece bien, puedes mantener tu voto para cerrarla.

Comment: Me parecía raro que hubiera votos negativos pero no votos de cierre. Si la pregunta parece *offtopic* o que no puede resolverse lo normal sería poner un flag o votar para cerrarla. Esta claro que cada uno puede votar lo que quiera y que no tiene ni porqué dar explicaciones pero se agradece cuando la gente explica los motivos como ha hecho @aparente001 dando su punto de vista del asunto

Comment: @blonfu tienes toda la razón. Se agradece poder tener una opción a réplica. No sería la primera pregunta que se me cierra por _off-topic_, en todo caso. Tal vez no me lo esperaba de esta, pero si es lo que la gente decide, lo acataré gustoso.

Comment: Pensaba pasar toda esta discusión a chat, pero entiendo que va a ser relevante mientras la pregunta siga abierta. **Quizá merezca la pena discutirla en Meta** y ampliar/clarificar los límites de este sitio? Desgraciadamente, veo ya tres votos negativos y si solo un usuario ha comentado por qué no piensa que es una buena pregunta no sé si vamos a poder obtener feedback adicional en Meta. Más cómodo que usar comentarios sí va a ser. Por cierto, siento haber hecho tanto hincapié en tu inexistente relato de Ci-Fi. Pesé que ayudaría a entender que esta pregunta es un ejercicio etimologico

Answer (score 6):

Creo que la palabra en cuanto a su uso y origen seria "**varón**" en cuanto a su uso para "hombre" o relativo a "hombre":

> féminas y varones

En cuanto a cualidades:

> femenino y varonil

Sin embargo en cuanto a género la palabra es "**masculino**".

Supongo que el opuesto a *feminismo* debería ser **varonismo** o **masculinismo** y no **machismo**.

*Machista* envuelve las características del género animal y no del ser humano. Mientras que *macho* puede ser aplicado a animales, *femenino* es solo aplicable al género humano.

Así como lo opuesto a **machismo** es **hembrismo**, lo opuesto a **feminismo** debería ser **varonismo**.

Para mí ambas palabras simbolizan la grandeza, individualidad, virtud y belleza de cada género.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, Erin, pero la pregunta se refería a la palabra "feminismo", no a "fémina".

Comment: Creo que la palabra deberia ser Varonilismo

Comment: Madre mía, acabo de darme cuenta de que en el enunciado he dicho "feminismo" y "feminista" indistintamente. Lo corrijo, mis disculpas.

Comment: gracias por la observacion @walen , ahora que lo veo "varonilismo" suean a nihilista

Answer (score 5):

Al `masculinismo` ya [propuesto anteriormente](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24425/5481) voy a añadir `virilismo`.

Para responder a esta pregunta me repasé un poco la etimología de "feminismo".

Como explican en [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feminismo#Etimolog%C3%ADa) empezó como un neologismo francés con un significado completamente distinto al actual (más por tema médico que de derechos sociales). Luego Alejandro Dumas lo usó con un sentido despectivo en uno de sus panfletos (más con el sentido de *afeminado*) "para desprestigiar a los varones que apoyaban decididamente el movimiento de mujeres que demandaban el acceso a sus derechos ciudadanos". De nuevo wikipedia aclara que

> No fue hasta la década de 1880, cuando Hubertine Auclert, sufragista francesa, retomó el término, ahora con una connotación dirigida a los movimientos que buscaban la justicia social y política para las mujeres.

*[Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?feminismo)* explica que "feminismo" viene de "fémina" y el sufijo -ismo (doctrina).

Lo opuesto a una fémina sería un varón, que nos daría `varonilismo` como apunta [Mike en su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/24452/5481). Pero también tenemos [viril](http://dle.rae.es/?id=btKqf5s%7CbtLZwGu),

> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al varón.
> 2. adj. Propio del varón o que posee características atribuidas a él.

que es lo opuesto a afeminado, además de relativo al varón.

Con "virilismo" tienes algo que no solo usa el opuesto de "fémina" si no que recoge un poco ese viaje "etimológico" del término hasta ser usado como se usa hoy en día.

`Virilista` podría ser un término despectivo para "desprestigiar a las mujeres que apoyan decididamente el movimiento de hombres" (vendría a ser un equivalente de "marimacho") y luego ese término podría perder las connotaciones peyorativas para identificar el término de la lucha contra el hembrismo.

[Varonil](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bOO3Dhj), tiene la misma definición que "viril" de acuerdo al DRAE, por lo que el ya propuesto "varonilismo" cuadraría también para reflejar ese viaje etimológico de "feminismo".

Answer (score 0):

El masculinismo sería sinónimo del feminismo ya que hembrismo no gusta ni tiene coherencia según vuestras exposiciones....  Si lo contrario del machismo es el hembrismo, y si el feminismo es la equivalencia de sexos, se debería poder decir indistintamente masculinismo en vez de feminismo... es decir, tanto feminismo como masculinismo serían la igualdad de sexos.