# ¿Existe la expresión "violencia feminista"?

Tags: significado

En España, cuando un esposo es violento con su esposa o un hijo es violento con la madre de este, se dicen que son violencias machistas. Parece que "violencia machista" tiene una connotación negativa, que no es equivalente a "violencia doméstica" (por ejemplo).

Y pues, si una esposa es violenta con su esposo o una hija es violenta con el padre de esta, ¿Se puede decir que son violencias feministas? Y si el hijo y el padre son violentos uno al otro, ¿se trata de violencias machistas? Y si la hija y la madre son violentas una a la otra, ¿se trata de violencias feministas? Perdonen por las posibles confusiones.

Comment: No lo he oído nunca, y no creo que se use. Quizá por las connotaciones de "machismo" y "feminismo" (tenemos en el stack algunas preguntas relacionadas con estos términos como [¿Cuál sería el opuesto etimológico de “feminismo”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24450/5481) y [¿Cuál es el antónimo de “feminismo”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24422/5481)). Aparte de "violencia doméstica"  se usa ""violencia intrafamiliar". Sospecho, que dicho término debería ser "violencia femenina", puesto que "feminista" tiene otras connotaciones (que en política se desambigua como "hegemónico")

Comment: el termino acuñado para denominar a la violencia por parte de mujeres a varones es "hembrismo" o "violencia hembrista"

Comment: ¿Alguien ha echado un ojo a lo que hay en la prensa in internet con esta frase exacta?  Voy a votar por cerrar porque faltó investigación previa, y porque la pregunta se presta para discusiones subjetivas.  Pero si quieres editar y cambiar el enfoque, quizás cambiaría mi voto.

Comment: Otro que cree que lo opuesto de «machismo» es «feminismo» (emoji de carapalma)… (sería «hembrismo»).

Comment: el termino aun no ha sido acuñado por completo y creo que la decision de este stack para resultados polemicos y cuestionables es siempre la de mantenernos al margen. somos responsables de cuidar el contenido que publicamos y no tenemos autoridad de dictar o imponer ninguna regla. Solo nos dedicamos investigar y dar una respuesta o en ocaciones proponer soluciones; pero siempre cuidando a la sensibilidad y seguridad de quienes nos puedan leer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

La "violencia feminista" no existe porqué el feminismo no es lo contrario que el machismo.

> Feminismo: Doctrina y movimiento social que pide para la mujer el reconocimiento de unas capacidades y unos derechos que tradicionalmente han estado reservados para los hombres.

Los tipos de violencia que comentas son TODOS violencia doméstica.

> Violencia doméstica: La violencia doméstica o violencia intrafamiliar es un concepto utilizado para referirse a «la violencia ejercida en el terreno de la convivencia asimilada, por parte de uno de los miembros contra otro, contra algunos de los demás o contra todos ellos»

La violencia machista es toda aquella violencia que se ejerza de un hombre hacía una mujer por el simple hecho de ser mujer.
Al no existir históricamente una cultura que "maltrate", infravalore o deje a los hombres en un puesto secundario de la sociedad, el término "violencia feminista" es totalmente incorrecto.
Sin embargo, podrías utilizar "violencia hembrista", el cual sólo sería válido en el caso de que la mujer ejerciera violencia hacia un hombre por el simple hecho de ser hombre.

Comment: Para no diferenciar sexos, se habla de "violencia de género".

Comment: Para no diferenciar sexos, se habla de violencia intrafamiliar. Violencia de genero es la violencia contra la mujer por razon de su sexo. No lo digo yo, lo dice la ley, la cual emana del parlamento.

Answer (score 5):

Los conceptos de *machismo* y *feminismo* no son paralelos y opuestos, como pueden serlo *macho* y *hembra* desde el punto de vista biológico o cultural.

El [machismo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NnO8B9D) se define como una forma de [sexismo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Xl6VetE) (discriminación por razón del sexo) con prevalencia del varón sobre la mujer. Esta palabra siempre ha tenido connotaciones negativas, de desigualdad o menosprecio de la mujer, por lo cual la expresión *violencia machista* es adecuada.

En cambio el [feminismo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=HjuyHQ5) es el principio de que los hombres y las mujeres son iguales (excepto en lo estrictamente biológico, se entiende). También se usa la palabra para designar a los movimientos que defienden este principio de igualdad. Aunque el feminismo político ha utilizado a veces tácticas de protesta violenta, no tiene relación con actitudes violentas individuales de mujeres contra hombres.

Entre ciertos opositores al feminismo político o como movimiento organizado se utilizan palabras como *hembrismo* o *[misandria](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PNfUuIF)* para caracterizar al feminismo. No creo prudente recomendar que uses estas palabras porque son, digamos, "inflamables". No quisiera entrar en terreno político, pero *hembrismo* es un término muy usado por movimientos **anti**feministas, y para algunas personas es un término misógino en sí mismo. Por eso yo no recomendaría su uso a nadie, especialmente a alguien que no domine totalmente el idioma. *Misandria* significa literalmente "odio o aversión a los hombres" y es un término aceptado, incorporado en el DLE y con cierta historia, pero en la práctica también se suele usar con sentido misógino.

Comment: Misandria es el odio xenofobico por el hombre, y es el equivalente a la misoginia, el opuesto a la violencia de genenero mas equivalente al machismo es el hembrismo.

Comment: +1 por esta diferenciación clave: *Aunque el feminismo político ha utilizado a veces tácticas de protesta violenta, no tiene relación con actitudes violentas individuales de mujeres contra hombres.* O sea, creo que se puede hablar de "violencia feminista" para referirse a manifestaciones violentas de un grupo de feministas.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus aportaciones! He aprendido mucho, de ustedes, con solo un hilo como este .

Comment: Se me olvidó comentar que es un poco confuso porque en muchos sitios web (los que he encontrado en mi búsqueda), el antónimo de "femenista" es "machista", y sin embargo resulta que el antónimo de "machista" no es "feminista".

Comment: @Mike No quiero entrar en terreno político, pero *hembrismo* no es una palabra que recomendaría usar a alguien que quiere aprender a expresarse en español. Añado ahora una aclaración al final de mi respuesta.

Comment: @Maurice En efecto, el antónimo de "machista" no es "feminista" pero eso no es algo que puedas consultar en un diccionario común, porque tiene más que ver con la historia y la cultura que con el léxico del idioma.

Comment: @pablodf76 pues no entiendo porque no, lo he comentado en otras preguntas relacionadas con este tema, si *feminismo* es la igualdad de los sexos y *machismo* la actitud de superioridad del hombre hacia la mujer, ¿no son ideas opuestas?

Comment: @blonfu Dicho así, sí, son ideas que se oponen conceptualmente, pero si lo planteas como si una fuera contrapartida de otra, el resultado es que parece que estás equiparándolas moralmente.

Answer (score 5):

Las posibilidades de un idioma, para la capacidad de nuestra mente, son infinitas en la práctica. Siempre hay una primera vez en la que se utiliza una expresión y, desde ese momento, existe, siempre que se atenga a las normas sintácticas y se le pueda dar un valor semántico. En el caso de las expresiones nuevas, es conveniente explicar qué se quiere decir si es posible la ambigüedad o malinterpretación. Esto, respecto a la formulación estricta de la pregunta.

Respecto al concepto, se han utilizado ya desde hace un tiempo respetable sustantivos como *masculinismo* (y sus derivados), no como oposición a *feminismo* sino como complemento de este en la búsqueda del igualitarismo en este campo; y *hembrismo*, como contraparte de *machismo*.

Hay un par de consultas a la RAE sobre esto.

[Respecto a *hembrismo*](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/776739133939220481):

> - Aly  @Aly_Ziah  16 sept. 2016
>
>   ¿Cuál es el término correcto para referirse a una mujer que defiende
>     la superioridad de la mujer?
> - RAE ‏Cuenta verificada @RAEinforma En respuesta a @Aly_Ziah. RAEconsultas
>
>   «Hembrismo» se usa en los textos como opuesto a «machismo»; es neologismo reciente y no figura en el diccionario.

Y [respecto a *masculinismo*](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/755742012326944772):

> - Enrique Ruiz @erik_dj_35 20 jul. 2016 @RAEinforma
>
>   ¿Cuál sería el antónimo de Machista?,¿Y de Feminista? Entiendo que
>     ustedes deben corregir para proteger nuestra lengua.
> - RAE Cuenta verificada @RAEinforma En respuesta a @erik_dj_35 RAEconsultas
>
>   ... los estudios dedicados a los papeles que el hombre y la mujer
>     desempeñan en la sociedad emplean «masculinismo».

Hay quien niega que el [masculinismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masculinismo) tenga motivo de existir y que el [hembrismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hembrismo) exista siquiera. Como puede comprobarse, la RAE no se mete en estas cuestiones: tan solo aclara sobre la corrección en la construcción del término y da cuenta de su uso registrado.